# I want to show the results of the spin in a popup instead of toast

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I'm having a little issue with my code 'Spinning wheel', I want to show the results in a popup instead of showing it in toast text
Here is the main activity of the code

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int index = getRandomIndex();
            luckyWheelView.startLuckyWheelWithTargetIndex(index);
        }
    });

    luckyWheelView.setLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener(new LuckyWheelView.LuckyRoundItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void LuckyRoundItemSelected(int index) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).topText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private int getRandomIndex() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(data.size() - 1) + 0;
}

private int getRandomRound() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(10) + 15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some version of a `Dialog`. You probably want an `AlertDialog`

The android docs outline these very well:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#AlertDialog

"The `AlertDialog` class allows you to build a variety of dialog designs and is often the only dialog class you'll need."

Answer (score 0):

firstly add this method in your activity :

```
   public void startAlert(String title , String message){
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(title);
builder.setMessage(message);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // here you can do anything you want
    }
});
builder.show();
}
```

after that call it in your code